# how to set global variable from onclick function and pass it to another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to create a difficulty system for my game, it's controlled by user choice through jquery.
index.html contains divs for new game, credits, & difficulty for the game. Then user could change the difficulty by choosing difficulty menu and difficulty choices will appear (Easy, Normal, Hard). 
Choosing new game will hides menu, and shows canvas to play the game.

### index.html

```
<ul id="difficulty">
     <li><a href="#" class="diff-link1" class="choice">
         <img class="diff-choice" src="images/Easy.png">
         <div class="diff-desc">9 Life </div>
     </a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="diff-link2" class="choice">
         <img class="diff-choice" src="images/Normal.png">          
         <div class="diff-desc">6 Life </div>
     </a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="diff-link3" class="choice">
         <img class="diff-choice" src="images/Hard.png">
         <div class="diff-desc">3 Life </div>
     </a></li>
</ul>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="500"></canvas> 
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script src="js/game.js"></script>
```

### menu.js

```
var difficulty = 2;    //Default, if user don't change difficulty 

$('.newgame').click(function() {
    $('#menu').hide();
    $('#wrapper').hide();
    $('#myCanvas').show();
    assetLoader.sounds.titleBgm.volume = 0; 
    assetLoader.sounds.bgm.volume = 0.5;
    assetLoader.sounds.bgm.loop = true;
    assetLoader.sounds.bgm.play();     
});

$('.credits').click(function() { 
    $('#menu').hide();
    $('#credit').show();
});

$('.diff').click(function() { 
    $('#menu').hide();
    $('#diff').show();
}); 

$('.diff-link1').click(function() { 
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
    difficulty = 3;              //set difficulty to easy
});

$('.diff-link2').click(function() { 
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
    difficulty = 2;                //set difficulty to normal
}); 

$('.diff-link3').click(function() { 
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
    difficulty = 1;             //set difficulty to hard
});  

$('.back').click(function(){
    $('#credit').hide();
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
});
```

### game.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var diffText;
var heroLife = difficulty * 3;
var immortal = true;
// Difficulties
if(difficulty == 1) {
    diffText = "Hard";
} else if(difficulty == 2){
    diffText = "Normal";
} else if(difficulty == 3){
    diffText = "Easy";
}

//Game logic,etc
```

My problem is, everytime i set the difficulty to anything, it always revert back to Difficulty = 2 (Normal Difficulty).
I tried to merge both js files into one big file, still same result :(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WELL do you update the game.js to use the new difficulty level? That code you posted is not going to magically re-run.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still new to this, but what do you mean by update the game.js ? by creating update() function to render the game etc? Do i have to use ajax to re-run the script ?

Comment: `if(difficulty == 1) { diffText = "Hard";.....` That code is not going to run again

Comment: is there any way i can re-run that code without refreshing the page ?

Comment: Depends on what that code does. But first step would be make it a method and call that method when it needs to update.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.diff-link1').click(function() { 
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
    document.myGlobal_difficulty = 3;              //set difficulty to easy
});

$('.diff-link2').click(function() { 
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
    document.myGlobal_difficulty = 2;                //set difficulty to normal
}); 

$('.diff-link3').click(function() { 
    $('#diff').hide();  
    $('#menu').show();
    document.myGlobal_difficulty = 1;             //set difficulty to hard
```

document is global. You can add what you want - but be care - dont re-write existing variables.

Comment: I tried adding document. to each variable but it's still doesn't work :(

Comment: try create your situation on jsfiddle - and i solve it

Comment: thank you, your solutions is almost the same that @Erick suggested, it changes the difficulties but not until i refreshed the page. hmm :\

Comment: so, ok, i can sugget to you 2 kind of solutions: 1) use location.hash 2) use session on the server-side - what your choose?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that it always reverts back to 2 because every time you select a difficulty, it will load the javascript file and it will go through the line:  var difficulty = 2;

One solution would be to create a hidden input field on your html and store the difficulty in there every time the user changes it. So you will be reading the new difficulty from the input tag (textbox). The input field would be something like:

```
<input type="text" id="global_difficulty" style="display:none;" value="2"/>
```

The default value will be 2.

Now, on the javascript, you can access the difficult using DOM like this:

```
var difficulty = document.getElementById("global_difficulty");
```

To set the different values, you would say something like:

```
difficulty.value = 3;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, it does work & the difficulty change based on user's choice, but not until i refreshed the page.

Comment: Oh I see. You want it to stay there permanently. In that case, instead of using a hidden field, you need to use a database where you permanently store the difficulty. If you create a mySQL database, you would have a table where you store this difficulty. Then, with PHP you can access this database. You would be able to retrieve the difficulty and display it on the client side.

Comment: is there any other way beside using database & php?

Comment: You could store the difficulty on an XML file and then read it using JavaScript. However, parsing XML is really slow. I don't have too much experience with it but if you want to use XML, I would recommend checking this website: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp